# Debugging Parse Cloud-Code

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code, back4app

What would be the best way to debug Parse Cloud Code? Currently it's a mess of logging to the console and checking logs. Does anyone have a good workable solution?

Answer (score 4):

During development, you should begin by testing against a local hosted server. I.e., I use VS Code. You can set breakpoints and watch variables for their values.  You can set up a tool like ngrok to get a remote URL for your local endpoint so you can test with non-local hosted clients if you'd like.

We also use Slack extensively.  We've created our own slack bot, and it has several channels it reports relevant information too, triggered from our parse-server. One of these is a dev error channel. Instead of console.logs, which are hard to sift through and find what you're looking for, we push important information to Slack. We don't switch every single console.log to a slack message, just the important "Hey something went wrong here's the information" messages. This brings them to our attention so we can identify and resolve them way faster. Slack is awesome. I recommend using slack, even on a solo project.

Answer (score 1):

at the moment you can access your Logs using a console.log() or console.error() for functions and all general logs of everything that happens with your app, at Back4App you can access using: Server Settings -> Logs -> Settings -> Server System Log.

Or functions and all logs generated by Parse server, they're: request.log.info() and request.log.error(), at Back4App you can access using: Dashboard -> Logs.

Comment: Thanks Natalie, but I wondering if there was a way of debugging the code, not just going through logs

Comment: Here i am, inheriting a project using Back4App and the built-in logs is just unacceptable, there is no history whatsoever. Useless.